# I am trying to create a timer-like system that will stop the script in javascript

Tags: javascript

I want to make a timer that will say "Too slow, you failed" after a few seconds. I am just doing this for fun and I enjoy running into problems. I am very new to coding.

```
var num1 = prompt("What is 5+15")
if (num1 == 20)
var num2 = prompt("What is 8*9")
else
alert ("You Failed!")
if (num2 == 72)
var num3 = prompt("What is 5*12")
else
alert ("You Failed!")
if (num3 == 60)
alert ("Good Job!")
```

Comment: then do it ....

Comment: `prompt` is blocking. You can't interrupt it with a timer.

Comment: You can't interrupt `prompt` (which is one of many reasons not to use `prompt`, `alert`, `confirm`, etc., except where absolutely necessary). Instead, look for tutorials on adding/removing elements to/from a page and or showing/hiding them (so you can add the question and then remove it when they're too slow) and look at `setTimeout` for the timeout. Once you've worked through a few tutorials, this'll be a piece of cake. If you run into a *specific* problem doing that, feel free to come back and post a question about that; folks will be happy to help.

Comment: If you are just learning, you really should use braces, semicolons, and proper indenting.

Answer (score 0):

You won't be able to interrupt a prompt, so you'll have to go about it a different way.

But since you're a beginner, to start a timer in JavaScript you use the [setTimeout function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers/setTimeout).

Which will look something like this:

```
var tooSlowTimer = window.setTimeout(function() {
 alert('TOO SLOW!');
 // Or any code you want ran when the timer is up
}, 2000); // Timer set to 2000ms, or 2 seconds
```

To disable the timer when the user answers, you will use the [clearTimeout function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers/clearTimeout)

Which will look something like this:

```
window.clearTimeout(tooSlowTimer);
```

Here is an example [CodePen](http://codepen.io/peteTalksWeb/pen/NRJKYJ)